# Can't run IIS Express 8 on Windows 7

Tags: windows, iis, iis-express

When I try to run IIS Express 8 with following command
`iisexpress.exe /trace:error`
on Windows 7 I get following error lines:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpress.exe/trace:error
Starting IIS Express ...
Failed while trying to preload CLR version v4.0.  hr = 80131700
Failed to initialize the W3WP_HOST  hr = 80131700
Process Model Shutdown called
Unable to start iisexpress."
```

How can I run IIS on my Windows?

Comment: Answer is there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15644577/2504433 (It helps me at the same situation)