# IIS express not working in visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis-express, iis-8

Iam not able to run the Visual Studio Application with IIS Express. Iam getting an Error “Unable to launch IIS Express” for the first time.
After multiple times debugging,
Iam getting the below error, [image]

If I run IIs express manually through command prompt,iam getting the below error,
[image]

I have reinstalled IIS Express but there is no change. I have also modified the application host config file of IIs express by deleting all the site names of application but there is no change.

Iam not able to know the issue. So, plz suggest any solution for fixing this issue.

Comment: just mention error text, its not viewable in form of images

Comment: If either answer worked for you mark the answer that worked as accepted

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and the problem is related to the app pool definition which you can find in \users{your username}\mydocuments\IISexpress\config\applicationhost.config.

Find the  tag

```
<add name="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
```

and change the managedruntimeversion from "v4.0" to "v4.0.30319" for .net 4.5

```
<add name="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0.30319" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Following suggetions that might be helpful to you>>

Use process monitor to watch the iis-express process to see if there are any permission issues when attempting to start it.

For that, follow this link>>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

If problem is security related then, run visual studio in run as administrator mode

As a last resort, you can disable the logging module by modifying the applicationhost.config, which is located in the `%userprofile%\documents\IISexpress\config` directory.

To do so you will need to comment out a some lines in the file.

Under the `<system.webServer>/<globalModules>` element, comment out the line

```
<add name="HttpLoggingModule" image="%IIS_BIN%\loghttp.dll" />
```

Under the `<location>/<system.webServer>/<modules>` element, comment the line

```
<add name="HttpLoggingModule" lockItem="true" />
```

After saving your changes try restarting iis express.