# Where is the template for applicationHost.config file stored

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

When I create a new Web application using VS2015, I get an applicationHost file created in the new .vs folder.  This file contains configuration information for IIS Express.

Where is the template for this file located?

Comment: Note: the reason that I needed to edit the applicationHost file was due to the following error message that I was getting when I attempted to Debug/Run:

"Unable to connect to IIS Express"

I needed to edit the .NET runtime version to fix the problem as mentioned in the following answer:

[stackoverflow.com/a/15644577/2504433](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584862/iis-express-not-working-in-visual-studio-2012/15644577#15644577)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the files at 2 locations (32Bit and 64Bit Program Folder) in my Windows 10 + VS2015:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer\applicationhost.config"


"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer\applicationhost.config"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was editing the file in the first location and it wasn't making a difference.  When I edited the file in the x86 folder, the changes came through in new projects I was creating.