# Can't run my project in visual studio 2015

Tags: model-view-controller

I built an MVC project and tried to run it on Visual Studio 2015. I haven't written any code yet. The build is successful and I get this message:

> "localhost refused to connect."

I wanted to stop the project but I realized it has't started. I am new in programming and this is my first project. I couldn't find any good answer on the web what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35418904/8516041)?

Try changing your port number (Right click solution > Properties > Web > Project Url).

[image: Project Url port number]

This may be caused by a conflicting port number.