# Visual Studio 2015 and IIS Express get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I need to debug an asp.net project. I want to debug the website using the debug function with Visual Studio 2015 through a browser. I just succeed in debugging before.

Now I'm getting this error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED after I try to start debugging.

I have already tried these solutions [How to solve ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to connect to localhost running IISExpress - Error 502 (Cannot debug from Visual Studio)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190881/how-to-solve-err-connection-refused-when-trying-to-connect-to-localhost-running)

and [localhost refused to connect Error in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352603/localhost-refused-to-connect-error-in-visual-studio)

But none of them are working.

It seems IIS Express is not binded to Visual Studio...

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html You need to run the report and edit your question to include the info.

Comment: I just realized that I cannot find my project in IIS express Sites. Should my project be there?

Comment: Sounds like you need to study where the configuration is https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved disabling in debuggers Native Code and SQL Server.

[image: Solution]