# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on IIS

Tags: windows, iis, connection

I have an application hosted on my local IIS (Windows 10).

From today I am not able to access the application in the browser (tried in Chrome, Browser and IE).

In the browser, I see '**ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**'. (Same behaviour if I try to 'Browse Website' from IIS.)
I tried browsing the **Default Web Site** on **localhost** and was a success.

I am able to ping the application from the command prompt.

There are no logs related to it in the IIS logs and the event viewer.

Comment: What host name did you use to access the application?Have you tried to disable other websites when you access the app? Have you tried to add a binding for https and access the website from https://localhost. You may receive connection_resfused when you force https in your application. Besides, could you see that error in C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In registry,
at path: `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters`

it was having 2 values
removed the second one, left the default one.

This fixed my issue.

Comment: This was it for me as well! My second entry in that registry path was "ListenOnlyList" set to 127.0.0.1.  I found another answer here on SO that explains doing this using `netsh` commands, no need to edit registry manually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45199591/411691